# DropDownLists Issue ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I really have a serious issues with postback, I have 3 dropdownlists, the first one contain data from a database, it's the countries, the second is the same but for the cities who depends the selected value on the first dropdownlist which is the countries, and the third dropdownlist is the airlines who depends on the selected value of the second dropdownlist which is the cities.

So the first two dropdownlists work perfectly, but the third dropdownlist will never work even with autopostback true and false, it will always refresh on to the first value and I wrote if(!IsPostback) so I really I'm frustrated about this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace Hijazi_Airlines
{
    public partial class Book : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAirlines"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                Sign.Text = "Sign Out";
            }
            else
            {
            }
            gather_countries();
            gather_cities();
            gather_Tocountries();
            gather_Tocities();
        }
        private void gather_date()
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT Depart FROM Flights where Airlines_id=" + Airlin.SelectedValue;
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                Response.Write(reader[0].ToString());

                sqlcon.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            sqlcon.Close();
        }

        private void gather_cities()
        {
            FromCit.Items.Clear();
            string cities = "select * from Cities where country_id = " + FromCount.SelectedValue;
            CountriesAndCities(cities, FromCit);
        }
        private void gather_Tocities()
        {
            ToCit.Items.Clear();
            string cities = "select * from Cities where country_id = " + To.SelectedValue;
            CountriesAndCities(cities, ToCit);
        }

        private void gather_countries()
        {
            string Countries = "select * from Countries order by country desc";
            CountriesAndCities(Countries, FromCount);
        }
        private void gather_Tocountries()
        {
            string Countries = "select * from Countries order by country desc";
            CountriesAndCities(Countries, To);
        }

        private void CountriesAndCities(string query, DropDownList dp)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmdC = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmdC.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                item.Value = reader[0].ToString();
                dp.Items.Insert(0, item);
            }

            sqlcon.Close();
        }


        protected void Hom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }

        protected void SignIN_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Sign.Text == "Sign Out")
            {
                Session.RemoveAll();
                Session.Abandon();
                Sign.Text = "Sign In";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void Contact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Contact.aspx");
        }

        protected void FromCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gather_cities();
        }

        protected void To_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gather_Tocities();
        }

        protected void Airlin_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gather_date();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Use `if (!IsPostBack)`, And you don't need to use `Page_Init`, `Page_Load` is better.

Comment: I already used the ```if(!IsPostBack)``` and it's not working and same for Page_Load, nothing would work :/

Comment: An approach to avoid use of postback is use ajax. Create a javascript script in your aspx file that manipulate this dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
string query = "SELECT Depart FROM Flights where Airlines_id=" + Airlin.SelectedValue;
```

You said that the third dropdownlist is the airlines who depends on the selected value of the second dropdownlist which is the cities. But in the above code you are selecting the value of third dropdown which makes no sense as it doesn't have any value.

So instead of above code, change the id value to this:

```
string query = "SELECT Depart FROM Flights where Airlines_id=" + YourCityDropDownId.SelectedValue;
```

Check this and let me know.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, i fixed that, but the DropDownList of the Airlines is always returning the first Value when selecting another

Comment: @Alou4a from the method that you written gather_cities() where is FromCount coming from?

Comment: Those are other dropdownlist, FromCount, FromCit, are two other dropdownlist, but the cascading three dropdownlists are To, wich is the To Country Dropdownlist, ToCit wish is the To City dropdownlist, and the Airlin wich is the Airlines DropDownLIST.

Comment: Well, the code looks good and it should be working. I hope this link will help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-one-dropdownlist-with-other-dropdownlist-in-asp-ne/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is permanently recreate ddl.

> ```
>         gather_Tocountries();
>         gather_Tocities();
> ```

Well, for solution this problem, you need after created your ddls set selected value for ToCit and To ddl.

```
ToCit.SelectedValue = yourValue; //Something like this;
```

But code which you wrote is not productive, because you each time call database

if you wanna init your ddl after select in prev, just call your method 
***CountriesAndCities*** in SelectedIndexChanged. First init you can do in **pageInit** or **pageLoad** but with use `if(isPostBack){your first ddl init}`

for example

```
PageLoad(){
  if(IsPostBack){
   string Countries = "select * from Countries order by country desc";
            CountriesAndCities(Countries, FromCount);
 }
}
```

For other ddl the same

then

```
protected void FromCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gather_cities();
}
```

Comment: i have in total 6 ddls, 2 ddls, From Country To Country, 2 other ddls From city, To City, and 2 other ddls, One is Airlines and One is Hotels, The first ddl From Country is bounded with From City, same for To Country and To city, after that, the ddl of Airlines is bounded with To City, same for hotel, so finally when a user select a country in From Country he will get the City in From city, same for To Country, he will get To city, and when he Choose a city From City, he will get the Airlines of the city Choosed in To City, that's why i have recreated the ddls