# DropDownList Issue ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the cascading Drop Down Lists, but in my case I have 3 DDLS and 1 calendar, on the Third DDl If I enable AutoPostBack it always returns the first value.

I really have a serious issues with postback, I have 3 dropdownlists, the first one contain data from a database, it's the countries, the second is the same but for the cities who depends on the selected value of the first dropdownlist which is the countries, and the third dropdownlist is the airlines who depends on the selected value of the second dropdownlist which is the cities, and at the end when I select an Airline in the third ddl, it need to select the date, but it only selects the first Airline, when I select another it will report the first value, Any Idea?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Hijazi_Airlines
{
    public partial class Book : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAirlines"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAirlines"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Countries", sqlcon);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                Country.DataSource = dt;
                Country.DataBind();

            }
        }

        protected void Hom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }

        protected void City_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Airline.Items.Clear();
            Airline.Items.Add("Select Airline");

            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAirlines"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Flights.*, Airlines.* FROM Flights INNER JOIN Airlines ON Flights.Airlines_id = Airlines.Id WHERE Flights.A =" + City.SelectedItem.Value, sqlcon);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            Airline.DataSource = dt;
            Airline.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Country_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            City.Items.Clear();
            City.Items.Add("Select City");

            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAirlines"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Cities where Country_id=" + Country.SelectedItem.Value, sqlcon);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            City.DataSource = dt;
            City.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Airline_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAirlines"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Flights where Airlines_id=" + Airline.SelectedItem.Value, sqlcon);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            sqlcon.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            Depart.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Depart"].ToString());
            Depart.VisibleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Depart"].ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Book.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hijazi_Airlines.Book" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>AirLines | Book</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Cabin_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">.main, .tabs ul.nav a, .content, .button1, .box1, .top { behavior:url("../js/PIE.htc")}</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page3">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="main">
  <!--header -->
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">AirLines</a></h1>
      <span id="slogan">Fast, Frequent &amp; Safe Flights</span>
      <nav id="top_nav">
        <ul>
          <li style="list-style-type:none"><asp:Button   class="nav1" ID="Hom" runat="server" Text="Home" ForeColor="White" Height="55px" OnClick="Hom_Click" /></li>
          <li style="list-style-type:none"><asp:Button   class="nav2" ID="Sign" runat="server" Text="Sign In" ForeColor="White" Height="55px" OnClick="SignIN_Click1" /></li>
          <li style="list-style-type:none"><asp:Button   class="nav3" ID="Contact" runat="server" Text="Contact" ForeColor="White" Height="55px" OnClick="Contact_Click" /></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="index.html"><span><span>About</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="offers.html"><span><span>Offers</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none" id="menu_active"><a href="book.html"><span><span>Book</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="services.html"><span><span>Services</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none" class="end"><a href="contacts.html"><span><span>Contacts</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- / header -->
  <!--content -->
  <section id="content">
    <div class="wrapper pad1">
      <article class="col1">
        <div class="box1">
          <h2 class="top">Hot Offers of the Week</h2>
          <div class="pad"> <strong>Birmingham</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot1 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 143.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
              <strong>London (LHR)</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot2 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 100.-</span><a href="book2.html">Geneva</a></li>
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 112.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Manchester</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot2 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 97.-</span><a href="book2.html">Basel</a></li>
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 103.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Edinburgh</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot2 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 165.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Birmingham</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot1 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 143.-</span><a href="book2.html">Beirut</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col2">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="Country" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"   
                    DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="id" AppendDataBoundItems="true"   
                    onselectedindexchanged="Country_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select Country--</asp:ListItem>  
                </asp:DropDownList>
          <br />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="City" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Cities"   
                    DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True"   
                    onselectedindexchanged="City_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select City--</asp:ListItem>  
                </asp:DropDownList>
          <br />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="Airline" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="AirlineNames"   
                    DataValueField="A" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Airline_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select Airline--</asp:ListItem>  
                </asp:DropDownList> 
          <asp:Calendar ID="Depart" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
        </article>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--content end-->
  <!--footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="links">Copyright &copy; Alaa Hijazi All Rights Reserved          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!--footer end-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.form_5').jqTransform({
            imgPath: 'jqtransformplugin/img/'
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tabs2.init();
    });
</script>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the controls, It's looking like the value/text values could be the problem.

Comment: here you go : ```

Comment: Yikes! This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: i will post and answer about it

Comment: i don't care about sql injection i just need it to work then i will see about the sql injection buddy

Comment: Do **NOT** post an answer to add information. Instead, edit the question to include the new information.

Comment: hahahhaha, im sorry im new to stakoverflow

Comment: It's also not okay to see about sql injection later. It's too important for that. Too often, 'check it later' becomes 'check it never', and it's not really any extra work to do it right the first time. The code as written is practically **begging** get hacked. When you hear you have an sql injection issue, fixing it should take precedence. Always. Even for local and intranet-only apps.

Comment: i just need to see the issue about why on 3 cascading ddl it's working , then when i add a 4 or a calendar to binded it with the third and enable post back on it, keep refreshing and forcing the first value, then i will check the sql injections, this issue is frustrating more then the sql injection issue

Comment: You say that now, but if someone exploits the injection issue, which could happen at any moment, they'll have the ability to drop whole tables, steal data, or inject malicious javascript into every string field (I've seen this actually happen), and I promise you that will take much more attention.

Comment: this is a beginner project, im still in uni, i really assure you that my teacher dont care about that...

Comment: i just need help in the ddls

Comment: It's still not okay. There are two things you should learn to do the right way, from the beginning, and they are sql injection and password handling. This is a big enough deal you need to never learn the bad habits in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DropDownLists Issue ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306876/dropdownlists-issue-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see your problem. You are setting the calendar dates to a specific date from the query, What you probably want to do is populate the available dates into another dropdown or some other list control so a user can select the date they want.

Answer (score -2):

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Book.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hijazi_Airlines.Book" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>AirLines | Book</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Cabin_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">.main, .tabs ul.nav a, .content, .button1, .box1, .top { behavior:url("../js/PIE.htc")}</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page3">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="main">
  <!--header -->
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">AirLines</a></h1>
      <span id="slogan">Fast, Frequent &amp; Safe Flights</span>
      <nav id="top_nav">
        <ul>
          <li style="list-style-type:none"><asp:Button   class="nav1" ID="Hom" runat="server" Text="Home" ForeColor="White" Height="55px" OnClick="Hom_Click" /></li>
          <li style="list-style-type:none"><asp:Button   class="nav2" ID="Sign" runat="server" Text="Sign In" ForeColor="White" Height="55px" OnClick="SignIN_Click1" /></li>
          <li style="list-style-type:none"><asp:Button   class="nav3" ID="Contact" runat="server" Text="Contact" ForeColor="White" Height="55px" OnClick="Contact_Click" /></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="index.html"><span><span>About</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="offers.html"><span><span>Offers</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none" id="menu_active"><a href="book.html"><span><span>Book</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none"><a href="services.html"><span><span>Services</span></span></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-type:none" class="end"><a href="contacts.html"><span><span>Contacts</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- / header -->
  <!--content -->
  <section id="content">
    <div class="wrapper pad1">
      <article class="col1">
        <div class="box1">
          <h2 class="top">Hot Offers of the Week</h2>
          <div class="pad"> <strong>Birmingham</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot1 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 143.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
              <strong>London (LHR)</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot2 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 100.-</span><a href="book2.html">Geneva</a></li>
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 112.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Manchester</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot2 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 97.-</span><a href="book2.html">Basel</a></li>
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 103.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Edinburgh</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot2 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 165.-</span><a href="book2.html">Zurich</a></li>
            </ul>
            <strong>Birmingham</strong><br>
            <ul class="pad_bot1 list1">
              <li><span class="right color1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; from USD 143.-</span><a href="book2.html">Beirut</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="col2">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="Country" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"   
                    DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="id" AppendDataBoundItems="true"   
                    onselectedindexchanged="Country_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select Country--</asp:ListItem>  
                </asp:DropDownList>
          <br />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="City" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Cities"   
                    DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True"   
                    onselectedindexchanged="City_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select City--</asp:ListItem>  
                </asp:DropDownList>
          <br />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="Airline" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="AirlineNames"   
                    DataValueField="A" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Airline_SelectedIndexChanged">  
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select Airline--</asp:ListItem>  
                </asp:DropDownList> 
          <asp:Calendar ID="Depart" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
        </article>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--content end-->
  <!--footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="links">Copyright &copy; Alaa Hijazi All Rights Reserved          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!--footer end-->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.form_5').jqTransform({
            imgPath: 'jqtransformplugin/img/'
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tabs2.init();
    });
</script>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may be a correct solution to the problem, it's not very helpful with any context of what this code is supposed to do or how it is supposed to fix the original problem presented.

Comment: hi please follow as [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)